# Python Object contains list of another object throws AttributeError

Tags: list, object, python-3.3

Python version 3.3 w/ Aptana IDE

I'm teaching myself python in my spare time at work so I decided to recreate a poker game that my friends and I play. To facilitate the various calls to different functions I created two objects. One object contains the data for the entire game, GameData, and the second object contains a single player, Player, that I am attempting to add to GameData.

The below code loops and attempts to add Player to a list in GameData but I get an error stating:

AttributeError: type object 'GameData' has no attribute 'players'

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, seat):
        self.seat = seat
        self.chips = 0
        self.wins = 0
        self.card = 0
        self.isDealer = False

class GameData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.games = 0
        self.numPlayers = 0
        self.chips = 0
        self.players = []
        self.deck = []
```

The below function throws the error

```
def testDealCards():
    gd = nuts.GameData #declare GameData object
    gd.deck = [7,5,5,5,3,1,5,6,1,2] #assign values to deck list
    for x in range(2): #loop to create player objects in GameData
        gd.players.append(Player)
    gd.players[0].isDealer = True
    gd.players[1].isDealer = False
    print(gd.players)
    nuts.dealCards(gd)
    assert gd.players[0].card == 5
    assert gd.players[1].card == 7
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the `GameData` class type instead of creating an object.

Try this:

```
gd = nuts.GameData()
```